# LIbgdx Background Image issue

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering

So here is my issue.  I have a 800x800 libgdx game and I have created a 800x800 .png using gimp.  I add it and draw it but the image now seems to be extremely larger than expected.  For instance, if I have a ocean .png, all that renders is a dark blue screen.  Seems like it is accepting my image but I am doing something else wrong.  Any help would be awesome.  Code is below.  The player and enemy both render fine and on top of the blue.

```
private Texture img;
private TextureRegion textureRegion;
float drawingWidth,drawingHeight;

//Constructor
public GameScreen(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    img = new Texture("tester2.png");
    img.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
    int width=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

    textureRegion=new TextureRegion(img,0,0,width,img.getHeight());

    drawingWidth=width;
    drawingHeight=Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); 
    
    Gdx.app.log(ID, "GameScreen is loaded! " + drawingWidth + " " + drawingHeight);
}

@Override
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    //buffer screen
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor((11f / 255.0f), (11f / 255.0f), (11f / 255.0f), 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    sb.begin();     
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    update(deltaTime);
    sb.draw(textureRegion,0,0,drawingWidth,drawingHeight);
    sb.draw(img, 0, 0);
    player.render(sb);
    enemy.render(sb);
    sb.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my testing it seems like your camera's viewport is improperly configured. If you are using an OrthographicCamera then you want to use OrthographicCamera.setToOrtho() to set the viewport. Right now the camera is set to display a 2x2 pixel corner of your image. HOVEVER, your example is not replicable and I don't know how you set up your SpriteBatch or your Camera, or anything for that matter so I may be off.

P.S. why are you drawing img and texture region when they are the same? img will just put the image in the bottom left corner, textureRegion will repeat a few times across the screen.